# map alt+shift+] in vim

Tags: vim

I want to map <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> to `gt` and `gT` (so it works like on Mac)

How do I do it because it doesn't seem to work if I simply do this:

```
map <A-S-]> gt
```

Somehow <kbd>]</kbd> needs to be escaped or something

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your definition there.  Vim will correctly map that combination but it doesn't do it in quite the way you expect.  What that mapping essentially says is

> When <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> is hit in addition to <kbd>]</kbd>

On a standard keyboard the <kbd>]</kbd> character when combined with <kbd>Shift</kbd> will produce `}`.  This means that Vim won't ever see the <kbd>]</kbd> in combination with <kbd>Shift</kbd> but instead sees just `}`.  You can leverage this though to get the behavior you're looking for.  Try the following mappings instead (assuming standard QWERTY keyboard)

```
:map <A-}> gt
:map <A-{> gT
```

Comment: this does NOT work for me... I'm on a Mac, in case that is relevant.

Answer (score 17):

When you want to remap keys in vim, it is often a good idea to go to insert mode, hit <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>, and then type the key you want to remap.  In this case, I get an `Escape` character (<kbd>Ctrl+[</kbd>) followed by `}`.

I do like using the `<A-}>` notation, but you could have solved the problem by editing your `.vimrc` file, entering the `map` text, then hitting <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> and hitting <kbd>Alt+Shift+]</kbd> and then adding `gt`.  You would end up with a line like

```
map ^[} gt
```

(but with an actual `Escape` character rather than a `^` and a `[` as I had to type here) and it would work.

P.S. When I tried this, <kbd>Alt+Shift+[</kbd> worked fine, but <kbd>Alt+Shift+]</kbd> seems to be already in use in my copy of vim.  I'm not sure exactly what it does but remapping it isn't working for me.  When I type

```
:map <A-}>
```

it prints `No mapping found.`

Comment: You're welcome!  :-)  Back in the day, I used that trick to figure out what escape sequence a dumb terminal would send for one of its special keys.

Comment: Works on a Mac (using the control-v method).

Comment: Using neovim, the `Ctrl+V` trick gives me`map <M-}> gt` instead of `map ^[} gt` (which is a good thing).